# MySQL Query to recursively obtain entries based on parentID

Tags: mysql

For this example, we have four tables.

- Difficulties
- Games
- Devices
- Schedules

The goal of this query is to have a schedule containing a single Game, then getting all of the games related to that game based on the ParentID in the games row.

The JSON data below explains this in detail, I believe

```
/* GAMES */ {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Mario Bros',
    parent: null
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Super Mario Bros',
    parent: 1
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Crazy Kong',
    parent: 1
}, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Mario Sunshine',
    parent: 2
}, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Dog Fights',
    parent: null,
}, {
    id: 6,
    name: 'War Thunder',
    parent: 5
}, {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Pacman',
    parent: null
 }

/* SCHEDULE */ {
    difficulty: 1,
    weekday: 1,
    game: 1
}, { 
    difficulty: 1,
    weekday: 1,
    game: 5
}, {
    difficulty: 2,
    weekday: 1,
    game: 7
}
```

In this data the schedule composes of a two games `(1, 5)` and in the games data, the game with the id `(1)` has three games that are related to it through the `parent`:

Super Mario Bros and Crazy Kong are directly related to the data with the `parent` being set to `(1)` and `Mario Sunshine` is indirectly related to game id `(1)` by having it's parent set to Super Mario Bros `(2)`

The other game with the id `(5)` which also has a difficulty id of `1` has one game related to it, which is `War Thunder` which has the parent set to 5.

Pacman has a difficulty of 2, so it will never be brought up unless you search for difficulty 2 from the schedule, then the other 6 games will never appear.

I need a query that can find all of the related games based on the base entry in the schedule, which is retrieved by difficulty id.

The game returned by a query like:

```
SELECT ALL RELATED GAMES FROM SCHEDULE WHERE DIFFICULTY = 1
```

should be:

- Mario Bros
- Super Mario Bros
- Crazy Kong
- Mario Sunshine
- Dog Fights
- War Thunder

Here's a SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7583/5

The goal is to find all entries recursively of the original id based on the parent ids of all rows in the table.

Relationship:

```
'Mario Bros': [
    'Super Mario bros': [ 'Mario Sunshine' ],
    'Crazy Kong': [],  
 ],
 'Dog Fights': [
    'War Thunder'
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

one possibility

```
SELECT schedules.*, games.name
FROM schedules
INNER JOIN games ON games.id = schedules.gameId or games.parentId = schedules.gameId
WHERE schedules.weekday = 1
AND difficultyId = 1;
```

here is a working demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7583/57

Comment: This doesn't return `Mario Sunshine` which should be returned, because it's parent id is 2, which was a game that had a parent id of 1. It should go infinite levels deep.

Schedule returns game id 1.  Games 2 and 3 are linked to 1.  Game 4 is linked to 2. So it should be returned as well.

Comment: I am not getting your point here. why the game with parent id 2 should be returned ? because Mario Bros has id = 1 , Super Mario Bros has parent id = 1 and Crazy Kong has parent id = 1 . how does parent id = 2 comes in picture? can you explain the requirement..  Are you looking for something like chaining through parent ids till top level?

Comment: This is what I mean by "recursive", think of it as a hierarchy where 1 is at the top. Think of them as Mothers and Daughters and Their children.  `(1) -> (2, 3) -> (4)`  Game id 4 "Mario Sunshine" should show, because it is a "daughter" of game id 2.

Comment: yes i got your point now.. You are looking for upto nth (last) child of a parent. recursively

Comment: That is Correct. @doriclazar 's answer yields correct results, but it's not recursive

Answer (score 0):

With up to 3 levels:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_sc (
id INT NOT NULL,
gameId INT,
name VARCHAR(255),
difficultyId INT,
weekday INT,
variation TINYINT(1) default false,
deviceId INT NOT NULL,
parentId INT DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO temp_sc (id, gameId, name, difficultyId, weekday, deviceId, parentId)
SELECT distinct sc.id, g3.id, g3.name, sc.difficultyId, sc.weekday, g3.deviceId, g3.parentId
FROM schedules as sc 
LEFT JOIN games as g1 ON g1.id = sc.gameId
LEFT JOIN games as g2 ON g2.parentid = g1.id || g2.id=g1.id
LEFT JOIN games as g3 ON g3.parentid = g2.id || g3.id=g2.id
WHERE sc.weekday = 1
AND sc.difficultyId = 1;

SELECT temp_sc.name as 'Game Name', temp_sc.gameId as 'Game ID', temp_sc.parentId as 'References ID', dev.name as 'Device' FROM temp_sc
LEFT JOIN devices as dev ON temp_sc.gameID = dev.id;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't hard-core this, as it is expected to go infinite levels deep.

Comment: That can be really complicated to do. I hope [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27775/loop-through-self-join-on-table-until-the-operand-column-is-null-completely) similar example will help then.

Comment: for now, this will work as we're not going several levels deep, but there's an error in your query when multiple devices are used, see this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61b0e/2  Could you try to fix it? Rows are showing up twice.